# JavaScript Bing Maps

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I need to get all visible Pushpin after 'viewschange' maps.

```
 Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchange', function (e) {
    // todo.
  });
```

Here are some points:

1. I have some markers on the map and records associated with it on the right panel besides the map. They are connected via numeric id, which is stored as a property of marker.
2. All the markers are stored in an array.
3. When the user zooms in the map, records, associated to only visible markers should be shown on the right panel.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what your question is or what you're having problems with. You've set up an eventhandler, which looks correct. I'd point you towards the Bing maps documentation.

Comment: I have many Pushpins on the map. After views change maps, I need to get visible pushpins on the maps.

Comment: If you listen for `viewchangeend` it will yield an object with map info like coordinates which you should then be able to filter your pushpins by.